# Ternary if operator inside a regular if one

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

In Java, if I use a ternary if operator inside a regular if, for example:

```
if ((x > y - z) ? true : callLongWaitedMethod(many, parameteres)) {
        loveTeddyBear();
}
```

will it execute the callLongWaitedMethod if `x > y - z` is indeed true? I hope it is not and I can use this nice statement, slightly complicated at the first glance, but more attractive to compare with the extra boolean variable:

```
boolean b = (x > y - z) ? true : callLongWaitedMethod(many, parameteres);
if (b) {
        loveTeddyBear();
}
```

especially if I'm using this inside a big loop which iterates over and over, so creating boolean each time will not be nice from the performance point of view while if I declare the boolean outside the loop, I may miss the neat because of the big size of the loop.

Comment: just a style comment - but coding to this type of behavior will just make it that much harder for the next guy to figure out what is happening. Either simplify so it is readable, or comment here to tell the intent.

Comment: All you are doing here is reinventing the *conditional or operator*.

Comment: In short - `NO`, and always KISS(Keep It Simple and Stupid).

Comment: @SophieSperner : I know it is ternary

Comment: Sophie, it is not OR; it is CONDITIONAL OR. Read all about it in the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`callLongWaitedMethod` will *not* be called if `x > y - z` is true.

Answer (score 6):

This will work as you hope, but it would be clearer to simply use the normal `||` operator to accomplish exactly the same result:

```
if ((x > y - z) || callLongWaitedMethod(many, parameteres)) {
        loveTeddyBear();
}
```

Comment: In your variant, callLongWaitedMethod will be executed anyway? That was the reason why I changed it to a ternary form.

Comment: No, callLongWaitedMethod won't be executed unless the first is false.  The `||` operator doesn't evaluate the second argument if the first is true.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Java Language Specification 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), the long method will only be evaluated if necessary:

> The operand expression not chosen is not evaluated for that particular evaluation of the conditional expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute `callLongWaitedMethod` when `(x > y - z)` is true you actually have to swap the expression:

```
if ((x > y - z) ? callLongWaitedMethod(many, parameteres) : true ) {
        loveTeddyBear();
}
```

Comment: No, if it is true, I do not need to execute it, I only need it if the simpler expression (x > y - z) is not true.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the answer you want. You could also just use debugging statements with a simple version of your code to see what gets executed as a way of verifying the behavior. Something like

```
if ((1 > 2) ? true : someSimpleMethod()) {
    System.out.println("true if");
}
```

And as your `someSimpleMethod()` have

```
public boolean someSimpleMethod() {
    System.out.println("calling someSimpleMethod()");
    return true;
}
```

From there you can swap 1 and 2 to see if the `someSimpleMethod()` would execute.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself as the coder, if you can't figure out what it's going to do, should you really be coding it that way?  why not just this:

```
if ( (x>y-z) || 
     (x<=y-z && callLongWaitedMethod(many, parameteres))) {
    loveTeddyBear();
}
```

This will make much more sense to the novice programmer who is not familiar with your code.

Comment: The second test of x,y,z is redundant.